# understanding complex SP in DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I need to make changes to an SP  which has a bunch of complex XML functions and what not

```
Declare ResultCsr2 Cursor For
       WITH
       MDI_BOM_COMP(PROD_ID,SITE_ID, xml ) AS (
       SELECT TC401F.T41PID,TC401F.T41SID,
        XMLSERIALIZE(
         XMLAGG(
          XMLELEMENT( NAME "MDI_BOM_COMP",
           XMLFOREST(
                     trim(TC401F.T41CTY) AS COMPONENT_TYPE,
                     TC401F.T41LNO AS COMP_NUM,
                     trim(TC401F.T41CTO) AS CTRY_OF_ORIGIN,
                     trim(TC401F.T41DSC) AS DESCRIPTION,
                     TC401F.T41EFR AS EFFECTIVE_FROM,
                     TC401F.T41EFT AS EFFECTIVE_TO,
                     trim(TC401F.T41MID) AS MANUFACTURER_ID,
                     trim(TC401F.T41MOC) AS MANUFACTURER_ORG_CODE,
                     trim(TC401F.T41CNO) AS PROD_ID,
                     trim(TC401F.T41POC) AS PROD_ORG_CODE,
                     TC401F.T41QPR AS QTY_PER,
                     trim(TC401F.T41SBI) AS SUB_BOM_ID,
                     trim(TC401F.T41SBO) AS SUB_BOM_ORG_CODE,       --ADB01
                     trim(TC401F.T41VID) AS SUPPLIER_ID,
                     trim(TC401F.T41SOC) AS SUPPLIER_ORG_CODE,
                     TC401F.T41UCT AS UNIT_COST
               )
              )
             ) AS CLOB(1M)
            )
             FROM TC401F TC401F
             GROUP BY T41PID,T41SID
            )

       SELECT
       RowNum, '<BOM_INBOUND>' ||
        XMLSERIALIZE (
         XMLELEMENT(NAME "INTEGRATION_MESSAGE_CONTROL",
          XMLFOREST(
                    'FULL_UPDATE' as ACTION,
                    'POLARIS' as COMPANY_CODE,
                    TRIM(TC400F.T40OCD) as ORG_CODE,
                    '5' as PRIORITY,
                    'INBOUND_ENTITY_INTEGRATION' as MESSAGE_TYPE,
                    'POLARIS_INTEGRATION' as USERID,
                    'TA' as RECEIVER,
                    HEX(Generate_Unique()) as SOURCE_SYSTEM_TOKEN
                    ),
                      XMLELEMENT(NAME "BUS_KEY",
                       XMLFOREST(
                        TRIM(TC400F.T40BID) as BOM_ID,
                        TRIM(TC400F.T40OCD) as ORG_CODE
                       )
                      )
                     ) AS VARCHAR(1000)
                    )
            || '<MDI_BOM>' ||
              XMLSERIALIZE (
               XMLFOREST(

                 TRIM(TC400F.T40ATP) AS ASSEMBLY_TYPE,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40BID) AS BOM_ID,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40CCD) AS CURRENCY_CODE,
                 TC400F.T40DPC AS DIRECT_PROCESSING_COST,
                 TC400F.T40EFD AS EFFECTIVE_FROM,
                 TC400F.T40EFT AS EFFECTIVE_TO,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40MID) AS MANUFACTURER_ID,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40MOC) AS MANUFACTURER_ORG_CODE,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40OCD) AS ORG_CODE,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40PRF) AS PROD_FAMILY,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40PID) AS PROD_ID,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40POC) AS PROD_ORG_CODE,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40ISA) AS IS_ACTIVE,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40VID) AS SUPPLIER_ID,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40SOC) AS SUPPLIER_ORG_CODE,
                 TRIM(TC400F.T40PSF) AS PROD_SUB_FAMILY,
                 CASE TRIM(TC400F.T40PML)
                    WHEN '' THEN TRIM(TC400F.T40PML)
                    ELSE TRIM(TC400F.T40PML) || '~' || TRIM(TC403F.T43MDD)
                   END    AS PROD_MODEL

                  ) AS VARCHAR(3000)
                 )
            || IFNULL(MBC.xml, '') ||
               XMLSERIALIZE (
                 XMLFOREST(
                   XMLFOREST(
                     TRIM(TC400F.T40CCD) AS CURRENCY_CODE,
                     TC400F.T40PRI AS PRICE,
                     TRIM(TC400F.T40PTY) AS PRICE_TYPE
                       ) AS MDI_BOM_PRICE,
                    XMLFOREST(
                      TRIM(TC400F.T40CCD) AS CURRENCY_CODE,
                      TRIM(TC400F.T40PRI) AS PRICE,
                      'TRANSACTION_VALUE' AS PRICE_TYPE
                      ) AS MDI_BOM_PRICE,
                    XMLFOREST(
                      TRIM(TC400F.T40INA) AS INCLUDE_IN_AVERAGING

                       ) AS MDI_BOM_IMPL_BOM_PROD_FAMILY_AUTOMOBILES

                      ) AS VARCHAR(3000)
                    )
                  || '</MDI_BOM>' ||
                  '</BOM_INBOUND>' XML
                     FROM (
                            SELECT
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                   ORDER BY T40STS
                                   ,T40SID
                                   ,T40BID
                            ) AS RowNum
                            ,t.*
                            FROM TC400F t
                     ) TC400F

                     LEFT OUTER JOIN MDI_BOM_COMP MBC
                     ON TC400F.T40SID = MBC.SITE_ID
                     AND TC400F.T40PID = MBC.PROD_ID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN TC403F TC403F
                      ON TC400F.T40PML <> ''
                      AND TC400F.T40PML = TC403F.T43MDL
                     WHERE TC400F.T40STS = '10'
                       AND TC400F.RowNUM BETWEEN
                         (P_STARTROW + (P_PAGENOS - 1) * P_NBROFRCDS)
                         AND (P_STARTROW  + (P_PAGENOS - 1) * P_NBROFRCDS  +
                              P_NBROFRCDS - 1);
```

Given above is a cursor declaration in the SP code which I am struggling to understand. The very first WITH itself seems to be mysterious. I have used it along with temporary table names but this is the first time, Im seeing something of this sort which seems to be an SP or UDF? Can someone please guide me on how to understand and make sense out of all this?

Adding further to the question, the actual requirement here is to arrange the data in the XML such a way that that those records which have TC401F.T41SBI field populated should appear in the beginning of the XML output..

This field is being selected as below in the code:

`trim(TC401F.T41SBI) AS SUB_BOM_ID`. If this field is non-blank, this should appear first in the XML and any records with this field value Blank should appear only after. What would be the best approach to do this? Using ORDER BY in any way does not really seem to help as the XML is actually created through some functions and ordering by does not affect how the items are arranged within the XML. One approach I could think of was using a where clause where `TC401F.T41SBI <> ''` first then append those records where `TC401F.T41SBI = ''`

Comment: Please do not deface your question, if you don't like it to stay, delete your answer and the question, however consider the user that have taken time to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer for my requirement. I had to add an order by field name after XMLELEMENT function

Comment: This answers something totally different than the original question. Be careful doing this in other tags, there are folks around here who will downvote you for that, and may even vote to close or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do is help with the CTE.

```
 WITH
   MDI_BOM_COMP(PROD_ID,SITE_ID, xml ) AS (
   SELECT TC401F.T41PID,TC401F.T41SID,
```

This just generates a table named MDI_BOM_COMP with three columns named PROD_ID, SITE_ID, and XML.  The table will have one record for each PROD_ID, SITE_ID, and the contents of XML will be an XML snippet with all the components for that product and site.

Now the XML part can be a bit confusing, but if we break it down into it's scalar and aggregate components, we can make it a bit more understandable.

First ignore the grouping. so the CTE retrieves each row in `TC401F`. `XMLELEMENT` and `XMLFORREST` are scalar functions. `XMLELEMENT` creates a single XML element The tag is the first parameter, and the content of the element is the second in the above example. `XMLFORREST` is like a bunch of `XMLELEMENT`s concatenated together.

```
    XMLSERIALIZE(
     XMLAGG(
      XMLELEMENT( NAME "MDI_BOM_COMP",
       XMLFOREST(
                 trim(TC401F.T41CTY) AS COMPONENT_TYPE,
                 TC401F.T41LNO AS COMP_NUM,
                 trim(TC401F.T41CTO) AS CTRY_OF_ORIGIN,
                 trim(TC401F.T41DSC) AS DESCRIPTION,
                 TC401F.T41EFR AS EFFECTIVE_FROM,
                 TC401F.T41EFT AS EFFECTIVE_TO,
                 trim(TC401F.T41MID) AS MANUFACTURER_ID,
                 trim(TC401F.T41MOC) AS MANUFACTURER_ORG_CODE,
                 trim(TC401F.T41CNO) AS PROD_ID,
                 trim(TC401F.T41POC) AS PROD_ORG_CODE,
                 TC401F.T41QPR AS QTY_PER,
                 trim(TC401F.T41SBI) AS SUB_BOM_ID,
                 trim(TC401F.T41SBO) AS SUB_BOM_ORG_CODE,       --ADB01
                 trim(TC401F.T41VID) AS SUPPLIER_ID,
                 trim(TC401F.T41SOC) AS SUPPLIER_ORG_CODE,
                 TC401F.T41UCT AS UNIT_COST
           )
          )
         ) AS CLOB(1M)
```

So in the example, for each row in the table, `XMLFORREST` creates a list of XML elements, one for each of `COMPONENT_TYPE`, `COMP_NUM`, `CTRY_OF_ORIGIN`, etc. These elements form the content of another XML element `MDI_BOM_COMP` which is created by `XMLELEMENT`.

Now for each row in the table we have selected `PROD_ID`, `SITE_ID`, and created some XML. Next we group by `PROD_ID`, and `SITE_ID`. The aggregation function `XMLAGG` will collect all the XML for each `PROD_ID` and `SITE_ID`, and concatenate it together.

Finally `XMLSERIALIZE` will convert the internal XML representation to the string format we all know and love ;)

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful..what i don't understand is how all the components of a PROD_ID and SITE_ID are fetched. How is this being made possible. Is it through the XMLAGGREGATE function? Sorry very new to XML in DB2. So basically want to understand what each of the XML functions heare are doing. I went through the documentation but its not layman enough for me to understand